# Importar Archivos a R

Tags: r, importación

Hay forma de importar archivos sin necesidad de hacer un único nombre de archivo?

Es decir:

```
SURTIDORES <- read_excel("/home/po11/Desktop/nombre1.xlsx")
```

Después

```
SURTIDORES <- read_excel("/home/po11/Desktop/nombre2.xlsx")
```

Que no haya necesidad de que coincida el nombre del archivo con el código  los encabezados de todos los archivos si serán iguales.

Comment: Bienvenido Pedro R. Orozco a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que buscas? ¿Importar múltiples archivos con distinto nombre en un único `data.frame`?

Comment: Si importar archivos provenientes de una base de datos donde cambia la fecha de descarga, e ingresarlos al data.frame ya programado

Answer (score 3):

La forma más sencilla, usando funcionalidad base (salvo `readxl`) podría ser:

```
library(readxl)

file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)
df.final <- do.call("rbind", df.list)
```

Detalle:

- Con `file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')` generamos una lista a partir del patrón `*.xlsx`, con lo cual tendremos en ella los nombres de los archivos que vamos a leer
- Con `df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)` recorremos implícitamente la lista y leemos cada archivo, el resultado será una nueva lista `df.list` dónde cada elemento será el `data.frame` generado a partir de cada archivo
- Por último, con `do.call("rbind", df.list)` combinamos todos los `dataframe` en uno único, obviamente la estructura de los mismos debe ser idéntica para poder combinarlos.

Ahora, si te animas a usar `tidyverse` (te lo recomiendo), puedes aprovechar el pipe `%>%` y las rutinas `map*` del paquete `purrr` para hacer algo muchísimo más simple y concreto:

```
list.files(pattern='*.xlsx') %>%    # Con la lista de archivos
    map_df(read_excel) -> df.final  # leemos los excel y retornamos un único df
```

Comment: En realidad solo importaria un solo archivo con nombre diferente cada que se cargue, y ese iria a data.frame, entonces con list.files es posible?

Comment: Si en la carpeta desde donde lees el archivo, hay uno solo, está solución te sirve tal como está. Puedes también ajustar con más precisión el patrón del nombre, por ej: nombre*.xlsx